# How to get React props outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a way to load the correct language of this script, and that info is a props value. Roughly put, it would look something like this:

```
class AddressInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <PlacesAutocomplete
        do={this.someStuff}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default scriptLoader(
  `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&language=${this.props.language}`;
)(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddressInput));
```

I understand that `this.props` isn't accessible outside the component, so how would I be able to get `scriptLoader` to get a dynamic value?

Comment: Can you add the code for ```scriptLoader```? Or may create a codesandbox?

Comment: You don't have to connect the component on export, just connect it within the `language` scope

Answer (score 0):

You're basically there. You even have the idea of making it an HOC. Here is the impelementation:

```
function scriptLoader(WrappedComponent) {
  return (props) => {
    const dynamicUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&language=${props.language}`;
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} url={dynamicUrl}/>
  }
}
```

The HOC is accepting a prop called `language`, creates the url, and passes it down to the wrapped component, under the prop name `url`. Obviously, all these prop names can be changed at your discretion.

```
// usage in the parent
<AddressInput language="en"/>

// what is available in your presentational component
class AddressInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.url) // https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&language=us
    return (
      <PlacesAutocomplete
        do={this.someStuff}
      />
    );
  }
}
```